# Include kendo-window in angular js directive:Error: Multiple directives [contgoPopup, kendoWindow] asking for transclusion

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to build a directive which will display a kendo window with a kendo tab strip in its body content.
It's a component I need to be reusable since I use it a lot in my web app.

Here is the flat html representation that I want to turn into a directive

```
<div style="padding:20px;" kendo-window="test" id="test" k-title="hello"  k-options="popupOptions"> 
    <div kendo-tab-strip k-content-urls="[ null, null]">
      <!-- tab list -->
      <ul>
       <li class="k-state-active">View</li>
      <li>Edit</li>
      </ul>
     <div style="padding: 1em">
     This is the view tab 
     </div>
     <div style="padding: 1em">
          This is the edit tab 
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

1) First step is creating the directive that wraps the kendo popup and this si where I'm having an issue
So basically, my directive includes the kendo-window widget  in its template and has transclude="true", since the content of the popup will different each time.
It seems "transclude" and "scope" cause some issues. 
Please have a look : http://plnkr.co/edit/c7qoKlh75s8aS7fazYSo